# Upload an image in wordpress using REST API

Tags: php, wordpress

Using rest api i can create a post, get blog category etc. but i cannot upload an image i am referring
https://github.com/WP-API/client-php/blob/master/library/WPAPI/Media.php
and

http://wp-api.org/#entities_media-meta_width

and my code is

```
$data = array('file'=>$filePath,'is_image'=>true);
print_r($data);

$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream');
$response = $this->api->post(WPAPI::ROUTE_MEDIA, $headers, $data);
```

they talk about [$data in $response = $this->api->post(WPAPI::ROUTE_MEDIA, $headers, $data);]
what are the key value pairs used in $data?

Comment: This really needs examples of what you've tried, where you've looked for answers and a title that wasn't written in all caps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it myself:

1. specify the file path
2. put necessary headers
3. send post request

Here is the code:

```
$filePath = 'URL of image'; //right click your fav img and copy url.
$imageData = @file_get_contents($filePath); //get image content
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset= UTF-8',
       'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='.basename($filepath)');
$response = $this->api->post('/wp-json/media', $headers, $imageData);
print_r($response);
```

Check the WordPress Media Gallery.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
1 open chrome browser.
2 install apps (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/rest%20client?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)
3 open this apps and use
```

> Screenshort

[image]

Comment: You use chrome browers for checking API

Comment: you use most post method for upload images

Comment: can you pls send the php code to do this.not this one.

Comment: thanks for your great effort .i am actually using                                                https://github.com/WP-API/client-php/blob/master/library/WPAPI/Media.php can you help in this way?